# Snap the mouse to the X and Y axes

Tags: highcharts

```
    crosshair: {
        snap: false
    },
```

Untied the lines from the point using the method above.
Now the lines are linked to the mouse movement.
Please tell me or give an example if there is.
How can I see the price on the Y-axis and the date on the X-axis in real time when the cursor changes?
Example in the photo below.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/roxxs1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the **crosshair.label** feature set the enabled property to true. Label could be customized in the format options.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ha0g3n64/

```
  xAxis: {
    crosshair: {
      snap: false,
      label: {
        enabled: true,
      }
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    crosshair: {
      snap: false,
      label: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '{value:.1f}' // One decimal
      }
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.crosshair.label

Comment: How do I remove the current price conflict?
I get a lot of errors due to yAxis on hover.
The current last price is updated every second.
http://prntscr.com/rpkb9g

Comment: Please reproduce your case on some online editor which I could work on with sample data.

Comment: It is a bug, which is already reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11480 please follow the thread there - I suggested the workaround.

Comment: Tell me the last moment:
The limit of 5 characters after the dot is not triggered in yAxis.   

crosshair: {
    snap: false,
    label: {
     enabled: true,
     format: function(){
      var valY = this.value;
      valY = valY.toFixed(5);
      return valY;
     }
    }
   },

Comment: Use the `format: '{value:.5f}' // 5 decimal` instead your function. Format is not an callback anyway. https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bxrpkoze/